# Cover the Backside of the UIButton view

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad

When I flip UIButton using key path `@"transform.rotation.y"`, I can still see the front side of the UIbutton.

Is there anyway I can hide buttons front view contents and show a plain backside?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, I believe what you want is not possible. A view or layer does not have a backside that is different from its front – if it did, it would need more properties to set its backside color etc. The `CALayer` class has a `doubleSided` property. If you set it to `NO` (`button.layer.doubleSided = NO;`), the layer is automatically hidden when it faces away from the viewer but that's probably not what you want.

As a workaround, place another view at the same coordinates/frame as your button that has your desired backside color. If you sets this view's initial rotation transform to 180 degrees, then set both layers to `doubleSided = NO` and then rotate both views by 180 degrees, the button should disappear and the other view should appear. Note that I haven't tried this out.

Comment: i Like the idea, but i choose an easy way of doing it. UIButton has an image view inside it and i just hide/Unhide it when the button is flipped. works for me